# Check for props length in JsRender

Tags: jsrender

I would like to show some text before an iteration over an object's properties (if there are any). I tried checking for it's length but that doesn't work. How can I do this?

As you can see below, `tmpl1` with `json1` is a normal loop with `props`, what I need is having `tmpl2` with `json1`, but `value.data` beeing like `json2`

That key is always defined, sometimes it has content (`json1`), some times is empty (`json2`)

HTML

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="tmpl1">
  {{props value.data}}
    <span>{{:key}}</span>
    <div>
    {{for prop}}
      <div>
        {{:#data.name}} - {{:#data.phone}}
      </div>
    {{/for}}
    </div>
  {{/props}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="tmpl2">
{{if value.data.length}}
  <h1>This is the content:</h1>
  {{props value.data}}
    <span>{{:key}}</span>
    <div>
    {{for prop}}
      <div>
        {{:#data.name}} - {{:#data.phone}}
      </div>
    {{/for}}
    </div>
  {{/props}}   
{{/if}}
</script>

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

JS

```
var json1 = {
    "value": {
        "data": {
            "keyA": [
                {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "phone": 123
                }
            ],
            "keyB": [
                {
                    "name": "bar",
                    "phone": 456
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};

var json2 = {
    "value": {
        "data": []
    }
};


var tmpl1 = $.templates("#tmpl1");
$("#result1").html(tmpl1.render(json1));

var tmpl2 = $.templates("#tmpl2");
$("#result2").html(tmpl2.render(json1));
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/matias/vuqefase/)

Comment: You say "but value.data being like json2". - So is value.data intended to be an array [], or an object {}?

Comment: Depending on certain conditions (on server side) I would get one of those, sometimes like json1 ({}) and sometimes like json2 ([])

Comment: So you want data.length  even when it is an {}, in the sense of number of properties on object - or only if it is an array? Your question/difficulty is still not clear to me.

Comment: I want to know beforehand if I have something to loop. I know I can just {{props}} and it would take care if it has something to loop for or not. I need to print something before the loop. I don't know how to check that. I if do {{if value.data}} it will always validate because it is defined, regardless of the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a helper:
http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers

```
{{if ~hasContent(value.data)}}
   <h1>This is the content:</h1>
```

with

```
function testForContent(data){
    for (var key in data) { 
        return true;
    };
    return false;
}

tmpl2.render(json1, {hasContent: testForContent}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking Boris example, I'm leaving here a jQuery implementation and the updated fiddle

TEMPLATE

```
{{if !~isEmptyObject(value.data)}}
  <h1>This is the content:</h1>
  {{props value.data}}
    <span>{{:key}}</span>
    <div>
    {{for prop}}
      <div>
        {{:#data.name}} - {{:#data.phone}}
      </div>
    {{/for}}
    </div>
  {{/props}}  
{{/if}}
```

HELPER

```
$.views.helpers({
    isEmptyObject: function(obj)
    {
        return $.isEmptyObject(obj);
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/matias/vuqefase/1/)

Comment: You can actually write simply: .views.helpers("isEmptyObject", $.isEmptyObject);. Also BTW you can simplify {{:#data.name}} to {{:name}} - and similarly for phone...